# Kernel vs User mode to access SPI hardware on Tegra 2

Tags: c#, hardware, cpu-registers, drivers

I am using C# / VStudio and developing code to run on Windows CE 7.0.

is it possible to directly configure/access hardware registers on my processor from my application code?

Is there an API to directly access hardware registers in User Mode, avoiding the development of a Kernel mode driver? (intuition tells me kernel mode drivers exist exactly to avoid this, but...)

I am using NVIDIA Tegra 2 computer-on-chip processor and would like to control SPI ports (but the answer about how to access hardware is probably relevant for most processors).

Comment: _"is it possible to directly configure/access hardware registers on my processor from my application code?'_ - pretty sure apps haven't been able to do that since _Windows 3.1 Protected Mode_

Comment: A kernel mode driver is then the only solution? BTW How does the driver take control of a hardware register/memory space to avoid clashes with other drivers?

Comment: Refer to the Windows Driver SDK.  I doubt you can do so from c#

Answer (score 0):

Tegra 2 has SPI controller but you need to configure kernel and device tree incase your OS doesn't how it. You can do it using this very amazing [article](http://neurorobotictech.com/Community/Blog/tabid/184/ID/11/Using-the-Jetson-TK1-SPI--Part-1-Why-is-SPI-important.aspx) series of SPI on Tegra, thought this is for TK1 but should be same for T2